# Join multiple tables used as Indexing - Laravel

Tags: sql, database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have three tables - Chairman, Designation, Members.

MY requirement is to map the member to chairman and assign member a role.

I was able to fetch the list of members under the chairman when I had chairman_id and designation_id in the members table.

Since the chairman change, most of the members stay intact. So I came up with an idea of indexing them

> Table - membermap
>
> id | chairman_id | designation_id | member_id

So the list is preserved how many chairmans come and go. I dont need to create new profile for new chairman rather than map to it.

I am now sure how do I do it,

So far I was able to pull the ID but I am not sure how do I join the tables

Tables

```
Chairman
id| name

Designation 
id|designation

Members
id|members
```

Here is my controller

```
$mapmember = Statechairman::findOrFail($id)->statechairmembersmap;
dd($mapmember);
```

In this Iam getting the statechairmembersmap but it's fetching all the result and not limiting the match.

I also tried to join the query using the DB

```
$mapmember = DB::table('statechairmen')
       ->join('state_chairman_members_maps', 'state_chairman_members_maps.chairman_id','statechairmen.id')
       ->join('statemembers','statemembers.id','state_chairman_members_maps.members_id')
       ->select('state_chairman_members_maps.*')->get();

   but this result show me the  Table - membermap but not the other results.
```

My Models:

Chairman :

```
public function statechairmembersmap(){



  return $this->hasMany('App\StateChairmanMembersMap','chairman_id','id');
}


public function statemembers(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Statemembers','chairman_id', 'id');
}

public function statedesignation(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Statedesignation','id','designation_id');
}
```

membermap:

```
protected $table = 'state_chairman_members_maps';
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function statechairman(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Statechairman','id');
    }

     public function statedesignations(){
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Statedesignation','designation_id','id');
     }

    public function statemembers(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Statemembers','members_id','id');
    }
```

Please assist me where I doing wrong.

Comment: add `, '=',` in between join queries

Comment: @ViperTecPro I added ,'=' but it not working, 
$mapmember = DB::table('statechairmen')
       ->join('state_chairman_members_maps', 'state_chairman_members_maps.chairman_id','=', 'statechairmen.id')
       ->join('statemembers','statemembers.id','=', 'state_chairman_members_maps.members_id')
       ->select('state_chairman_members_maps.*')->get();

It is still showing me only StateChairmanMembersMap table result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for checking the question out. 
Finally after a lot of strugle, I was able to find it by myself.

```
 $mapmembers = DB::table('state_chairman_members_maps')
    ->join('statechairmen','statechairmen.id','=','state_chairman_members_maps.chairman_id')
    ->join('statemembers','statemembers.id','=','state_chairman_members_maps.members_id')
    ->join('statedesignations','statedesignations.id','=','state_chairman_members_maps.designation_id')
    ->where('chairman_id','=',$id)
    ->get();
```

Here is what I came up with.

Here I have joined 3 tables and mapped the id comming from the chairman to filter the result. I getting the results.